# How expensive is db.stats()?

Tags: mongodb

I need to ping a mongodb database on a regular basis and was wondering if it would be safe to execute db.stats() on every ping.  By "safe" I mean that db.stats() would be a "cheap" operation that would not disrupt or lower the overall db performance.

Comment: How often are you pinging your MongoDB server? Collecting `dbstats` can have an impact if you have a large number of databases & collections to iterate, but the best way to confirm the impact of your ping frequency would be to test in a representative environment. For a comparison point, the MMS (MongoDB Management Service) monitoring agent collects `dbstats` every 10 minutes by default and throttles frequency of collection if the command takes too long to return (see: [How does MMS gather database statistics?](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/faq/#how-does-mms-gather-database-statistics)).

Answer (score 1):

`db.stats()` takes a read lock, but overall is not a very costly operation. However the time required to run the command depends on the total size of the database. As the command must touch all data files it may take several seconds to run.